# Watch multiple variables with complete name unknown

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular controller as follows:

```
function SignUpController($window, accountService) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.errors = null;
  vm.user = null;

  vm.submit = function (user) {

    accountService.signup(user)

      .then(function (response) {     
        $window.location.href = "/";
      })

    .catch(function (response) {
      vm.errors = response.data.errors;
    }

  };

}
```

The API returns a list of errors, in case they exist, as follows:

```
[
  {code: "name", "message": "the name is required"}
]
```

When there are errors I add this list to vm.errors. In HTML I have:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="SignUpController as vmsignup" ng-submit="vmsignup.submit(vmsignup.user)">
  <input ng-model="vmsignup.user.email" name="vmsignup.user.email" type="text" />
  <span class="error" validator="vmsignup.user.email"></span>
  <!-- Other form fields -->
</form>
```

The directive is watching vm.errors and fills all spans with validators with the correct error message.

**In my controllers I always use vm.errors but in my html I often use something else, like vmsignup**, as I might have multiple controllers.

So in this example the directive must have vmsignup.errors to make it work:

```
angular.module("app").directive("validator", validator);
validator.$inject = ["$parse"];

function validator($parse) {

  var validator = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return validator;

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {

  scope.$watch("vmsignup.errors", function (errors) {

    if (errors) {

      var result = errors.filter(function (error) {

        if (error.code == null) 
          return false;

        var position = attributes.validator.lastIndexOf(".");

        if (position > -1)
          return attributes.validator.slice(position + 1).toLowerCase() === error.code.toLowerCase();
        else
          return attributes.validator.toLowerCase() === error.code.toLowerCase();

      });          

      if (result.length > 0) {
        element.show().text(result[0].message);
        return;
      }

    }

    element.hide();

  });
}
```

I would like the directive to have something like:

```
scope.$watch("vm*.errors", ...
```

I suppose this is impossible but there must be a way to solve this, no?

**I think the solution might be to have a new directive "validation"** used on the form to say what is the model:

```
<form name="form" ng-controller="SignUpController as vmsignup" validation-model="vmsignup">
```

Then I would use this on the validator directive:

```
scope.$watch(validator.model + ".errors", function (errors) {
```

Is this a good option? Can this be done? Can someone help me out?

Comment: You should describe better the problem that you want to solve. Maybe showing more code.. I feel that you could choose another solution to reach the same result.

Comment: @manzapanza Fair enough. I just updated my question with more code and explaining what I am doing and what is the "small" problem I would like to solve. Does the extra code and information helps? I did not miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watchGroup for this purpose

Comment: But can I use "vm*.errors" in watch group where * means anything? Remember that vmsignup is just an example ... I might have any vm* in my application

Comment: Reading about whatchGroup I don't think it accepts expressions ... The values must be well defined ...

Comment: Yes. Expressions wont work with any of the $watchers. If you know your variables need to be watched before hand, you can use $watchGroup.

Comment: I do not know the name of the variables before hand that is why I update my question with a solution that might solve the problem but I am looking for some help in it because I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Please check the below code and see if it is helpful for your application.

Comment: What code below? WatchCollection? No because I would need to place all view models names in my directive and keeping it updated.

Comment: Sorry.. I can not attach the code here.. let me check how to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109703/discussion-between-ambegodas-and-miguel-moura).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `*` as wildcard in a `$watch` expression, but you can watch for example a collection with `$watchCollection`...

An array of properties:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[prop1, prop2]', function(newValues, oldValues){
  var newProp1 = newValues[0];
  var newProp2 = newValues[1];
});
```

An array of functions returning a value:

```
$scope.$watchCollection([
    function(){
        return prop1;
    }, function(){
        return prop2;
    }
], function(newValues, oldValues){
  var newProp1 = newValues[0];
  var newProp2 = newValues[1];
});
```

**UPDATE**

as @Ambegodas said, you can pass the `errors` collection as parameter to your directive. So your code become:

```
angular
  .module("app")
  .directive("validator", validator);

validator.$inject = ["$parse"];

function validator($parse) {

  var validator = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return validator;

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {

    scope.$watch(attributes.errors, function (errors) {

      if (errors) {

        var result = errors.filter(function (error) {
          if (error.code == null) return false;
          var position = attributes.validator.lastIndexOf(".");
          if (position > -1) {
            return attributes.validator.slice(position + 1).toLowerCase() === error.code.toLowerCase();
          }
          return attributes.validator.toLowerCase() === error.code.toLowerCase();
        });

        if (result.length > 0) {
          element.show().text(result[0].message);
          return;
        }
      }

      element.hide();

    }, true); // << objectEquality == true

  }
}
```

**DIFFERENT SUGGESTED APPROACH**

You could create server side validations for those input that you can't validate only with client side validations.

HTML:

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-submit="vm.submit(vm.account)">

  <div class="form-group" mt-show-errors>
    <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" mt-validate-username class="form-control" name="username" id="username" ng-model="vm.account.username" required>
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.username.$touched">
      <span ng-show="form.login.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
      <span ng-show="form.login.$error.mtValidateUsername" class="help-block">Username already taken</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- more inputs -->

</form>
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
  angular
    .module('app.directives')
    .directive('mtValidateUsername', mtValidateUsername);

  function mtValidateUsername($timeout, MyAccountService) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: false,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var timeoutId;
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
          if (!inputValue) return '';
          $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
          timeoutId = $timeout(function () {
            MyAccountService.validateUsername(inputValue).then(function () {
              modelCtrl.$setValidity('mtValidateUsername', true);
            }).catch(function(){
              modelCtrl.$setValidity('mtValidateUsername', false);
            });
          }, 1000); // 1 second throttle
          return inputValue;
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I know but that is not a good solution as I would need to have a collection of all view models names inside the directive ... Hard to control something like that. Can a validation directive be created and validator access it? See my updated question ... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below approach.

```
      var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

  app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.errors =1;
    $scope.change = function(){
      $scope.errors = 2;
   }

});

  app.directive('myDirecitive',function(){

     return {
       restrict:'A',
       link:linkFunction
    }

    function linkFunction(scope,element,atrrs){            

       scope.$watch(atrrs.varName,function(newval,oldval){
         console.log("watcher called");
      });
    }

 });

  <body ng-app="MyApp", ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
   <h1>Sample Application</h1>
   <input type="text" my-direcitive var-name="errors"/>     
   <button ng-click="change()">Watch</button>     
  </body>
```

Comment: My idea was having at the form label a directive named validation-errors="errors" instead of having it in all inputs since is the same in all of them ...

Comment: Yep. This is similar to yours. I tested it and it works. The way i am accessing the variable inside the directive is little different.